# How to override the Search Button in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, search, button, windows-phone-8

I'm developing an application for Windows Phone 8 that gets content like messages list, or clients list.

I need to override the Search Button to search into the current page or to navigate to a search page included in the app (Search.xaml).

Please help me to change the button's default behaviour.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The application have a MainPage containing links to other pages: Messages, Projects, Offers.

I'm going to add the search page, but i thought that using the search button to go to search page would be better and more logic: like the search button in Windows 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override the hardware search button with the current SDK.

Comment: What's the recommended solution to solve the problem and to implement this feature, by respecting the windows phone user experience ?

Should I add a simple button in the app to perform the navigation to a search.xaml page ?

Comment: There's no real solution since there's no way to override the hardware button in the bottom right hand corner of the phone. You can have buttons, or other UI elements, within your app take you to `search.xaml` but that means the user will have to run your app to press it.